# What's difference meaning 'a period of time' preposition?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I am still solving TOEIC workbook.
However, I have difficulty understanding preposition meaning the 'a period of time' such as `over, until, from, by`.

Here is problem on my TOEIC workbook.

> The owner confirmed that the shopping mall's facilities will be upgraded ____ the next few months. 
>   a) until b) toward c) from d) over

I selected the (a), but my workbook's commentary said (A) until and (C) from is used to write 'certain period'.

So, I think that commentary mean is that 'over' is meaning relative time and writing 'until', 'by', 'from' is in front of  absolute time.

That's right?

I want to know detailed difference among the preposition that is meaning 'a period of time'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "abstract time" or "detailed date".  Do you mean something like "the next five days" vs. "August 5th, 2018"?

Comment: @stangdon Yes you are correct

Comment: OK.  I would call the first one a *span or period* of time and the second one a *precise* or an *exact* date.

Comment: I'd call that relative or absolute time. Just like a relative (from here) or absolute (from the top level) directory path.

Comment: @Davo Okay i will edit this question, according to your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **...over the next few months.**

This is properly grammatical. It means from now, and continuing for a few (normally 3-4) months.

> ...until the next few months.

This is not standard AmE usage; ***...until three or four months from now*** would be standard, and would mean starting now (or already in progress) and continuing until 3-4 months from now.

> ...from the next few months.

This is not standard AmE usage, and different people would probably assume different things, including "*starting a few months from now.*

> **...by the next few months.**

This is properly grammatical. It means on or before a date up to four months from now.

Additonally:

> **...for the next few months.**

This is properly grammatical. It means starting now (or having already started), and continuing for a few (normally 3-4) months.

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-the-following-over-the-next-few-months.2889123/ may be helpful.